# Npgsql 8.0 no longer works when request is mapped from a protobuf request with repeated field

Tags: .net, dapper, npgsql

Code using Npgsql 7.x and Dapper works ok on net 8.
But doesnt work with Npgsql 8.0.

```
public class Location { public NpgsqlPoint Point { get; set; } }

public async Task<IEnumerable<Location>> GetLocationsAsync(DomainParams paramObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new(_connectionString))
{
await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
return await conn.QueryAsync<Location>("select point from locationsTable where id = ANY(@ids)) ", new { paramObject.Ids } );
}    }
```

Error:

> "Depth": 0,
> "HelpURL": null,
> "HResult": -2147467262,
> "ClassName": "System.InvalidCastException",
> "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
> "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
> "StackTraceString": "   at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.g__ThrowWritingNotSupported|1_0(Type type, PgSerializerOptions options, Nullable 1 pgTypeId, Nullable 1 npgsqlDbType, Exception inner)\n   at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.GetTypeInfoForWriting(Type type, Nullable 1 pgTypeId, PgSerializerOptions options, Nullable 1 npgsqlDbType)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ResolveTypeInfo(PgSerializerOptions options)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.ProcessParameters(PgSerializerOptions options, Boolean validateValues, CommandType commandType)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 434

Later Edit: I updated the title/description to match the actual problem

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: I added the error stack trace in the description above

Comment: What's the return type for your function?

Comment: I added the full function in the description above

Comment: You don't need parsing if you can read the actual spatial types. Try [registering the NpgTopologySuite type plugin](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html?q=spatial&tabs=global) either globally or at the connection level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams the problem was on the param object which although was mapped in a parent code function from a protobuf request

```
var paramObject = new ParamObject() { Ids = protoReq.Ids };
```

Now on net 8 only when using Npgsql 8.0 they would still somehow reach the initial protobuf object property 'Ids' and give this error:

> at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.g__ThrowWritingNotSupported|1_0(Type type, PgSerializerOptions options, Nullable`1 pgTypeId, Nullable`1 npgsqlDbType, Exception inner) in /*/src/Npgsql/Internal/AdoSerializerHelpers.cs:line 58
> at Npgsql.Internal.AdoSerializerHelpers.GetTypeInfoForWriting(Type type, Nullable`1 pgTypeId, PgSerializerOptions options, Nullable`1 npgsqlDbType) in /*/src/Npgsql/Internal/AdoSerializerHelpers.cs:line 46
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameter.ResolveTypeInfo(PgSerializerOptions options) in /*/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlParameter.cs:line 565
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.ProcessParameters(PgSerializerOptions options, Boolean validateValues, CommandType commandType) in /*/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlParameterCollection.cs:line 739
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__119.MoveNext() in /*/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1444
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__119.MoveNext() in /*/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1596
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__112.MoveNext() in /*/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1309
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__33`1.MoveNext() in /*/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 434

The fix was to force a Tolist() in the mapping:
var paramObject = new ParamObject(){ Ids = protoReq.Ids.**ToList()** };

So I still belive there is some issue in the NpgsqlParameter.ResolveTypeInfo of Npgsql 8.0 as the code works totaly fine with net 8 with Npgsql v 7.x.

Comment: It would be great if you could put together a minimal repro that uses Npgsql directly (without Dapper) - if so, please post that on the Npgsql repo and we'll look into it.